# c# Chart Label Positioning

Tags: c#, charts

I am trying to move the position of a label that i am setting at a specific point on my chart line to explain what the line is and what the value used was to create the line.  The problem i am encountering is that the label goes right through the line. Is there a way that i can Move the label to the right to keep it from crossing lines.

[image]

Here is how i am setting the Label

```
chart1.Series["ZAV"].Points[average + (average / 2)].Label = 
              string.Format("ZaV = {0:n2}", zavSG);
```

**Work Around**

Although this doesn't exactly answer my original question that I posted, this is what I did. I made a new Series added one point at the location I wanted the label, in my case the very top right of my graph, and set the label to that point.  In the chart properties I set the chart series properties for SmartLabelStyle to not allow the label outside the plot area.

[image]

```
double maxPointX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
double maxPointY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum;
chart1.Series["Series6"].Points.AddXY(maxPointX, maxPointY);
chart1.Series["Series6"].Points[0].Label = string.Format("ZaV = {0:n2}", zavSG);
chart1.Series["Series6"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: You need to have access to the generated label control. It is possible in WPF, but I think that you use a different framework.

Comment: You can always use a TextAnnotation for this..